# How to I carried out Textbox value from ViewState when I postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, viewstate

> I want to know that how can I trace out the value of Textbox from ViewState.

As user enters any value into `Textbox`  and `click submit button` because of `postback` `Textbox` value disappears ,

But if I used `ViewState` in this case , then is there any way to see or display that value from `Viewstate`?

```
<html>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" /
    </form>
</body>
</html>

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text += "X";
}
```

Comment: Just get it from the control, that's what the ViewState is doing: making sure the controls are prepopulated.

Comment: I assume that you have code like this in `Page_Load`: `TextBox1.Text="initialvalue";`. If so, wrap it in `if(!IsPostBack){//...}`

Comment: yes it is inside  if(!IsPostBack){//...}

Comment: are you sure that textbox value disappear on **PostBack** ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your page load use this.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (ViewState["Values"] == null)
            {
                ViewState["Values"] = new string();
            }
        }

        TextBox1.Text = ViewState["Values"].ToString();
    }
```

After that use this.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewState["Values"] += TextBox1.Text;
    }
```

In the first Page_Load method, You will create a ViewState if its not a postback and its null. After that write the textbox your viewstate, in Button1_Click you will add your new textbox1 to your viewstate.